# Cannot invoke initializer for type '' with an argument list of type ''

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-playground

UPDATE: This works in Playground and inside a new project but just not inside my current project:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'User' with an argument list of type '(name: String)'

Any ideas as to what is causing this? I'm using Swift 2.0

```
class User {
    var name: String
    init (name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
let user1 = User(name: "User")
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm4Fk.png

Comment: Check your braces. Do you really want `let user1 = ...` *inside* the class definition?

Comment: thx for the reply, and nope, but putting it outside makes no difference :/  `class User {
    var name: String
    init (name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
let user1 = User(name: "User")`

Comment: That compiles without problems in my Xcode 7.

Comment: Ok, this is weird: the exact same code in the exact same place in a new project compiles just fine  (updated the question)

Comment: [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/vLdo9OK.png)

Comment: You have two errors in your screenshots, what's the other ? Don't you ever have a User class in the project ?

Comment: var name is of string and not set value make it 
var name : String!
then init(name : String) {
....
}

Comment: Ever figure this out? I'm experiencing the same thing. Clean doesn't help

Comment: sometimes there can be things you miss, especially if whitespace is concerned. I'm not saying this is the case here but for making comparison  life simple you should be using FileMerge tool. You'll find it under XCode>Open Developer Tools. Works like version editor. @John sometimes Clean isn't enough, Folder Clean (Cmd-Alt-Shfit-K) is required

Answer (score 1):

This is not the definitiv answer, but it might be the reason that there is another type (protocol, class, struct, enum, PAT,...) called `User` somewhere within the errorneous project that does not take a string in it's initializer. I remember having experienced that error caused by an accidental name collision.